# Firewall : firewalld with docker open port for local service

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker, firewalld, ufw

I'm trying to open port for ssh on non-standard port like `12452`, i used these commands and non of them worked

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 12452 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 12452 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 12452 -j ACCEPT
```

and used `firewalld` too and i used active zone is docker so i used:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=docker --add-port=12452/tcp
```

and still doesnt work...but actually i realized port 22's rule for ssh which i am using currently is not opened anywhere!!!
not even in the `iptables` rules!

note: i had `ufw` installed before and i just removed it

my `iptables-save` output is like this :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Mon Aug 14 20:51:29 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-INGRESS - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Aug 14 20:51:29 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Mon Aug 14 20:51:29 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-INGRESS - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -o docker_gwbridge -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s x.x.x.x/x ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s x.x.x.x/x ! -o docker_gwbridge -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker_gwbridge -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:x
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Aug 14 20:51:29 2023
```

and `firewall-cmd --zone=docker --list-all` output is like this:

```
docker (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: docker0 docker_gwbridge
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 12452/tcp
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Is `sshd` actually bound to that port? Are you running an obsolete OS or just running obsolete `iptables` commands?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why but seems like `firewalld` is still using `public` zone!!!

i tried opening port on public zone like this

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=12452/tcp`

and surprisingly it worked!!!

Comment: Curious that the same command from your question: `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=12452/tcp` didn't work earlier.

Comment: @JeffSchaller i didn't use that command earlier i don't know why i putted in my question!!!!!!!